# SonarQube LCOM4 ,RFC , Package tangle index has no data

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, rfc

I am using SonarQube 4.0 . I try to created a project and run sonar-runner successfully I could see most metrics there.

But when I try to add widgets for LCOM4, RFC and Package design (to show the package tangle index), it shows "No data".

I am not sure what's wrong with my configuration, should I turn on some configuration or install some additional plugins to show LCOM4, RFC and Package tangle index?

I am running sonar-runner on plain file folder (not from SCM , didn't have POM file) , not certain if this is the cause.

If anyone has idea about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must analyze .class files.

If you have not already done it, here is the parameter to add to your analysis configuration

```
# Comma-separated paths to directories with binaries (optional), in case of Java - directories with class files
sonar.binaries=build/classes
```